# Can't get multi-mapping to work in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, multi-mapping

Playing around with Dapper, I'm quite pleased with the results so far - intriguing!

But now, my next scenario would be to read data from two tables - a `Student` and an `Address` table.

`Student` table has a primary key of `StudentID (INT IDENTITY)`, `Address` has an `AddressID (INT IDENTITY)`. `Student` also has an FK called `AddressID` linking into the `Address` table.

My idea was to create two classes, one for each table, with the properties I'm interested in. Additionally, I put an `PrimaryAddress` property of type `Address` onto my `Student` class in C#.

I then tried to retrieve both student and address data in a single query - I mimick the sample that's given on the [Github page](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping):

```
var data = connection.Query<Post, User>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; });
var post = data.First();
```

Here, a `Post` and a `User` are retrieved, and the owner of the post is set to the user - the type returned is a `Post` - correct?

So in my code, I define two parameters to the generic `Query` extension method - a `Student` as the first which should be returned, and an `Address` as the second, which will be stored onto the student instance:

```
var student = _conn.Query<Student, Address>
                  ("SELECT s.*, a.* FROM dbo.Student s 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Address a ON s.AddressID = a.AddressID 
                        WHERE s.StudentenID = @Id", 
                    (stu, adr) => { stu.PrimaryAddress = adr; },  
                    new { Id = 4711 });
```

Trouble is - I get an error in Visual Studio:

> Using the generic method
>   'Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(System.Data.IDbConnection,
>   string,
>   System.Func,
>   dynamic, System.Data.IDbTransaction,
>   bool, string, int?,
>   System.Data.CommandType?)' requires 6
>   type arguments

I don't really understand why Dapper insists on using this overload with 6 type arguments...

Comment: I had exact same problem and it took me a while to figure out why - as Sam explains!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That would be cause I changed APIs and forgot to update the documentation, I corrected the error.

Be sure to have a look at [Tests.cs](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/Tests.cs) for a full up-to-date spec.

In particular, the old API used to take in an `Action<T,U>` to perform the mapping, the trouble was that it felt both arbitrary and inflexible. You could not fully control the return type. The new APIs take in a `Func<T,U,V>`. So you can control the type you get back from the mapper and it does not need to be a mapped type.

I just tied up some additional flexibility around multi mapping, this test should make it clear:

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

class Extra
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public void TestFlexibleMultiMapping()
{
    var sql = 
@"select 
1 as PersonId, 'bob' as Name, 
2 as AddressId, 'abc street' as Name, 1 as PersonId,
3 as Id, 'fred' as Name
";
    var personWithAddress = connection.Query<Person, Address, Extra, Tuple<Person, Address,Extra>>
        (sql, (p,a,e) => Tuple.Create(p, a, e), splitOn: "AddressId,Id").First();

    personWithAddress.Item1.PersonId.IsEqualTo(1);
    personWithAddress.Item1.Name.IsEqualTo("bob");
    personWithAddress.Item2.AddressId.IsEqualTo(2);
    personWithAddress.Item2.Name.IsEqualTo("abc street");
    personWithAddress.Item2.PersonId.IsEqualTo(1);
    personWithAddress.Item3.Id.IsEqualTo(3);
    personWithAddress.Item3.Name.IsEqualTo("fred");

}
```

Dapper pipes all the multi mapping APIs through a single method, so if something fails it will end up in the 6 param one. The other piece of the puzzle was that I did not allow for some super flexible splits, which I just added.

Note, the `splitOn` param will default to `Id`, meaning it will take a column called `id` or `Id` as the first object boundary. However if you need boundaries on multiple primary keys that have different names for say a "3 way" multi mapping, you can now pass in a comma separated list.

So if we were to fix the above, probably the following would work:

```
 var student = _conn.Query<Student,Address,Student>
              ("SELECT s.*, a.* FROM dbo.Student s 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Address a ON s.AddressID = a.AddressID 
                    WHERE s.StudentenID = @Id", 
                (stu, adr) => { stu.PrimaryAddress = adr; return stu;},  
                new { Id = 4711 }, splitOn: "AddressID").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: OK, thanks - but how can I add some criteria like `StudentId = @Id`  (and then set `@ID = 4711`) to this multi-mapping query??

Comment: @marc_s keep in mind there are a ton of optional params to control stuff like command type, command timeout and so on. one really important one to learn is "buffered" which allows you to buffer the results so you don't have SqlReaders stepping on each other

Comment: Great stuff - thanks so much for your response, works like a charm now!! One last gripe: it works on .NET 4 only - any hope you'll backport to .NET 3.5 ?? I'm still very much stuck on .NET 3.5 for a lot of projects, unfortunately....

Comment: @marc_s cheers, it should be pretty straight forward to backport it would involve removing all traces of `dynamic` and `optional params`, I totally support having a backport of dapper in a contrib project in the main repo if you feel up to it. nobody has picked up this project yet

Comment: @Sam - it would be pretty easy (I think) to do a backport (probably to 2.0 if needed) via compiler symbols. We can also (IIRC) configure nuget to deliver the most appropriate dll. (says the fool who has parallel support for c# 1.2 upwards, on multiple different BCLs/CLIs for pb-net)

Comment: @Marc Gravell, @Sam Saffron: YAY ! A NuGet-powered, .NET 2 through .NET 4 compatible Dapper - is it Christmas already? :-)

Comment: @marc_s I honestly don't think it is much work. The only trick is writing a build packager so you don't have to do multiple builds manually

Comment: @Sam in case it was unclear, I'm happy to take that piece of work - I'm not volunteering on your behalf :)

Comment: @marc_s - I just pushed support for this; just add CSHARP30 as a build symbol

Comment: @SamSaffron Unless I'm mistaken, this example is a one-to-one scenario: a person has one address. Is it possible to use multi-mapping to get an Order and that order's OrderItem objects? Say the object representation of that was order.items[x], etc. Or should I just use Dapper's multiple-results functionality instead?